# using multiple #define statements to create urls

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I want to define a base URL in my app:

```
#define kBaseURL @"http://mydomain.com/"
```

And the also be able to create other URL's using this as a base

```
#define kProductsURL @"/products"
```

I know I could do something like this:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", kBaseURL,kProductsURL];
```

How do I alter the `kProductsURL` I can just use `kProductsURL` with having to do the string formatting?

I know there is a ton you can do with the `#define` statements but I have not been able to find a good tutorial or documentation.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: For that simple case I would prefer `NSString * const baseURL = @"http://mydomain.com/";` and possibly even declare it `extern` in a header somewhere (to hide the actual value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could concatenate `#define`s simply as follows:

```
#define kBaseURL     @"http://mydomain.com"
#define kProductsURL kBaseURL@"/products"

// kProductsURL becomes http://mydomain.com/products
```

---

**Edit:** Building on other answers and comments...

However [some developers](http://qualitycoding.org/preprocessor/) consider using `#define` to be a code smell. An alternative would be to use `const`s. This has advantages over using `#define` as when you edit the content of a `const` it will not require a compilation of the entire project.

`URLs.h` file:

```
extern NSString * const kBaseURL;
extern NSString * const kProductsPath;
NSString *GenerateMyURL(NSString *path);
```

`URLs.m` file:

```
NSString * const kBaseURL = @"http://mydomain.com";
NSString * const kProductsPath = @"/products";

NSString * GenerateMyURL(NSString *path)
{
    return [kBaseURL stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];
}
```

Usage:

```
NSString *productsURL = GenerateMyURL(kProductsPath);
// Do whatever...
```

Comment: Please use `stringByAppendingPathComponent` instead of `stringWithFormat`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

```
#define kBaseURL(extension)  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mydomain.com/%@", extension]
```

and next use in your code :

```
NSString *urlString = kBaseURL(kProductsURL);
// urlString becomes http://mydomain.com/products
```

++

Comment: you could also make it a real function, perhaps NS_INLINE and put it in a header... just a thought to avoid the #define... also could include logic to derive the base url that way (based on branding or localization).